# .NET: "identity\\..*" does not match "identity.requesttoken"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match a string in .NET `Regex`, I want the expression to match "identity." with anything added to the end (can still limit the scope of * later on), testing the pattern in any `regex`editor works just fine (I have one less backslash there, due to escaping).

I have set a `breakpoint`right on my `Regex`.`IsMatch`to check the values, there are exactly what I put in the title (note that this is from the VS2010 debugger, escape sequences are unparsed)

Comment: They do match. You probably switched the parameters. :D

Comment: Indeed, I did. I feel bad now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a string literal (prefix the string with `@`) when specifying your regex. This will remove the need for you to escape the `\`:

```
Regex.IsMatch("identity.requesttoken", @"identity\..*")
```